# Non integer input causes infinite loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, while-loop, cin

i created a code for my final project. where in the start the user is asked what calculator to use its either the average calculator or simple calculator. but if the user accidentally entered a non integer it causes in infinite error loop but if its an integer that is not in the choices it works because i created a while loop. i need help what do i need to do to prevent the infinite loop.

```
cout << 1. average calculator: << endl;
cout << 2. simple calculator: << endl;
cout << Enter the Number << endl;
cin >> choice;
while (choice > 2 || choice <= 1)
{
cout << "Error! Please choose a number between 1 and 2 only." << endl;
cout << "Enter the number again:";
cin >> choice;
}
```

Comment: If the input doesn't match the expected type, then the input will not be extracted from the buffer, and will be left for your next attempt. I recommend you read whole lines into strings instead (use `std::string` and `std::getline`) and then use e.g. `std::stoi` to attempt numeric conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the input buffer. Also the condition in this if statement is incorrect

```
while (choice > 2 || choice <= 1)
```

It seems you mean

```
while (choice > 2 || choice < 1)
```

The while loop can be rewritten as do-while loop the following way

```
#include <limits>

//...

bool input_error = false;
do
{
    input_error = false;

    if ( not ( std::cin >> choice ) )
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
        input_error = true;
    }
    else if ( choice < 1 || choice > 2 )
    {
        input_error = true;
    }

    if ( input_error )
    {
        std::cout << "Error! Please choose a number between 1 and 2 only.\n";
        std::cout << "Enter the number again: ";
    }
} while ( input_error );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "1. average calculator:" << endl;
cout << "2. simple calculator:" << endl;
cout << "Enter the Number" << endl;

string stringInput;
getline(cin, stringInput);
int choice = atoi(stringInput.c_str());
while(choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
    cout << "Error! Please choose a number between 1 and 2 only." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number again:";
    getline(cin, stringInput);
    choice = atoi(stringInput.c_str());
}
```

You should read whole line, store it in string, and then convert that string to `integer` using `atoi()`. `atoi()` expects `c-string` to be passed so `std::string` should be converted to `c-string`. It is done by `stringInput.c_str()`.

I changed while condition`(choice > 2 || choice <= 1)` to `(choice < 1 || choice > 2)` because it says to enter number between 1 and 2, but with your condition entering number 1 would print `"Error! Please choose a number between 1 and 2 only."`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `while` loop, you could use a `switch` like this

```
switch(choice //this is the input)
{
   case 1:
       //the stuff you want to do
       break; //always a break
   case 2:
       //more stuff
       break;
   default:
       //throwing a error
       std::cout << "Error, please pick a number between 1 and 2\n";
 }
```

and if you want to repeat until you pick the right number, you could put the `switch` inside a `do while` loop like this

```
do
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        //the stuff
    }
}while(choice > 2 || choice < 1);
```

let's hope this will work
have a nice day.